# Any way to buy buildings not for sale in The Guild 2?

Tags: guild-2

I'm playing `The Guild II - Pirates of the European Seas` and there are often houses/businesses for sale in the beginning that I cannot afford. Eventually I do have the money and I'd like to buy them rather than build a "copy". But then they are not for sale.

Is there a way to get them to be on sale?

Answer (score 3):

i think killing the owner will get the building to go one sale. You can find out who the owner is by clicking on the building and right clicking andd holding on the picture. you can check which buildings are on sale at the city hall. when you select city hall, there should be an option to check what is on sale.

Comment: Building up on this: Yes, this is true, but sometimes the person who inherits the building may decide to keep it. You may have to murder the entire family. It always goes on sale if it's unowned (you killed everyone) though.